# Add Element to Canvas JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

So I want to add elements or items to a canvas through a `GraphicsContext`.
For example, to add a Rectangle, I don't want to use `fillRect(...)`, I want to create a `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(...)` and add it to my GraphicsContext,
So I can perform changes on that `rect`.

Something like this :

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.setHeight(100);
rect.setWidth(100);
rect.setFill(Color.BLACK);
DragResizeMod.makeResizable(rect, null);
```

then added it to

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.add(rect); //somehow
```

There is a solution which is to use a `Pane` instead of `Canvas` but I don't think it the best way, since a `GraphicsContext` run on a single thread.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

Adding Rectangles to a properly configured Pane is the way to go. I don't understand what your problem with this approach is. This is the way JavaFX works and you will probably not be able to change this.